# Get Plone 4 to import pictures as images and not files when uploading with webdav

Tags: upload, uploadify, plone, webdav, image

I remember back in Plone 2 days I found a simple hack to make one CMFPhoto folder receive webdav files as images (and show them as a gallery).

In Plone4 the images are received as content type files which are not very useful.

Other mass uploading options seem not to be updated to recent versions of Zope/Plone, except uploadify, which makes my server unable to start when installed with buildout.

Functioning webdav would be ideal

Thanks for any ideas, although I can't say I have understood the framework enough to use just a hint

Steen

Comment: While I couldn't reproduce this, I got other errors (http://dpaste.com/576724/). If you don't know how to work around your error, I'd suggest opening a ticket at http://dev.plone.org/plone. IIRC, WebDAV has been neglected in recent years.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you need to take a look in the Content Type Registry tool within your site and figure out the settings related to the image (png, jpg) extensions and mime-type that are configured for your site.  Visit the Zope Management Interface of your site, and go to ./content_type_registry in he root of your site to take a look.

The more complicated answer is that folders in Plone have a method called PUT_factory() that controls what items get created as.  Different folder types can behave differently, but all stock folder types in Plone and most add-ons should obey (unless a bug) the settings in the Content Type Registry.